# How to set a img in my aspx page through javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, image

Maybe it sounds stupid, but I really can't figure out how to set an `<img>` code in my .aspx page throught JavaScript.

My code so far:

```html
<%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Teste.aspx.vb"  Inherits="Teste" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">

Latitude: <asp:TextBox ID="nr_latitudeTextBox" runat="server" MaxLength="12" /> <br />
Longitude: <asp:TextBox ID="nr_longitudeTextBox" runat="server" MaxLength="12" /><br />

<asp:Button ID="cmb_mapa" runat="server" Text="Mapa" OnClick="cmb_mapa_Click"/><br />
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

                function fonte(lat, lon) {
                    var src = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=lat,lon&zoom=8&size=540x280&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false";
                    testando("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=lat,lon&zoom=8&size=540x280&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false", 540, 280, "Mapa");
                }

                function testando(src, width, height, alt) {
                    var img = document.createElement("img");
                    img.src = src;
                    img.width = width;
                    img.height = height;
                    img.alt = alt;
                    document.body.appendChild(img);
                }
        </script>

    <div id="img">

    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

Partial class:

```vb
Partial Class Teste
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page


    Protected Sub cmb_mapa_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmb_mapa.Click
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "testando", "testando(" & nr_latitudeTextBox.Text & "," & nr_longitudeTextBox.Text & ");", True)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`testando` first parameter is the image url and you're not providing it.

It seems you want to call `fonte` and not `testando` on your `RegisterStartupScript`. That's the method that takes latitude and longitude as parameters.

**EDIT**

Change

```
var src = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=lat,lon&zoom=8&size=540x280&ma‌​ptype=roadmap&sensor=false"
testando("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=lat,lon&zoom=8&size=540x280&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false", 540, 280, "Mapa");
```

by

```
var src = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + lat + "," + lon + "&zoom=8&size=540x280&ma‌​ptype=roadmap&sensor=false";
testando(src, 540, 280, "Mapa");
```

Fixed two things:

1) You weren't using `lat` and `lon` as parameter for the map url so fixed `src` building

2) Added `src` as parameter for `testeando` since you weren't using it

Comment: I changed RegisterStartupScript to fonte, and my last line from my function `fonte` to this:
     testando(src, 540, 280, "Mapa");
But now, it only shows a blue image, not my map.
I think (not sure) that the problem is in this line:
    `var src = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=lat,lon&zoom=8&size=540x280&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false";`

because of my `center=lat,lon`, but really don't know...